# Phone storage is very low

Tags: samsung, insufficient-memory

Samsung duos
total space as shown in system storage is 4 Gigabyte. But application manager shows total space of 60 'Mb'?
i cant install any application.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please start with taking a look at our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which holds some background and first-aid on this frequently asked question.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving some apps to SD card in app settings